# DotNetZip consuming all CPU resources during extraction

Tags: c#, performance, dotnetzip

I have a process that extract a lot of zip files using DotNetZip. This process must be a background process because user can be using the machine during the extractions.
In older machines (for instance 1,5Ghz, 1Gb RAM) it's consuming all CPU and slowing down the machine. I've tried to lower the process priority and thread priority, but it continues slowing down the machine. Someone got any ideas?

Comment: It's running as fast as it can - if it's spawning another process for some reason or another thread, you'll have to explicitly set that thread to a lower priority as well. (Or your entire process, assuming it didn't spawn another process )